# diagnosing battery drain -ford Taurus 97 - fuse 23

Tags: ford, wiring, battery-drain, taurus

pulling out fuses one at a time, i isolated the leak to:

- fuse 23 - leaking off-scale (> 250mA at 12V) - "Wiper system,variable assist steering, remote entry, anti-theft"
- fuse 24 - leaking ~180mA - "Integrated control panel, speedometer, electronic automatic temperature control module"

how do i proceed with finding and fixing the leak?

PS:

- Manuals and wiring diagrams [here](https://archive.org/details/97-taurus-manuals).
- This is a very old car - I don't care about anti-theft or remote entry features - didn't even know the car was capable of such!
- The multimeter I have can only measure up to 250 mA - trying to borrow something better (will edit once I get it).

Comment: Why off-scale? Change the range then we know what we are looking at...Also, anti-theft will be working ...

Comment: >250mA is at least .25A, which is a lot. Between the two that's >.47A, which is way  higher than normal. However, it's perfectly normal for those 2 to have some drain, the alarm in the first one and the clock in the second, however at a much lower rate, so I suspect the readings are wrong, maybe 25 and 18 mA rather than 250 and 180mA.

Comment: The *highest* current drain I could find for modern real time clock chips was 2mA and "low power" ones take only 0.2mA. If the OP's clock is really taking 180, either Ford design crappy electronics or something is wrong somewhere!